# cron expression to run a job every hour but only on weekdays?

Tags: cron

I have found that to run a job every hour I need to use the expression
    `0 * * * *`

But how do I make it run only on weekdays or alternately only on weekends?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
0 * * * 1-5
```

This website is really good for CRON scheduling:
[https://crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/)